# Input fields based on how many results in SELECT command

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Is there an appropriate way to get input forms based on how many results there are from your SELECT? I have this, but when it gets posted to the next page only the last result appears.

```
<?php 

$query = sprintf("SELECT promocost FROM Items, Promotions, Vendor_Prices, Vendors
WHERE Items.itemid = Promotions.itemid AND
Vendors.vendorid = Promotions.vendorid AND
Vendor_Prices.vendorid = Vendors.vendorid AND
Vendor_Prices.itemid = Items.itemid AND
promoid = '$promoid'");

$result =mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
die($message);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$models = $row['promocost'];
echo "<input type='text' name='promocost[]'/>";
}
?>
```

EDIT:
Took out unnecessary variable.

```
<?php 

$query = sprintf("SELECT promocost FROM Items, Promotions, Vendor_Prices, Vendors
WHERE Items.itemid = Promotions.itemid AND
Vendors.vendorid = Promotions.vendorid AND
Vendor_Prices.vendorid = Vendors.vendorid AND
Vendor_Prices.itemid = Items.itemid AND
promoid = '$promoid'");

$result =mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
die($message);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<input type='text' name='promocost[]'/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm gonna guess that the processing isn't done entirely in the loop: where is `$models` being used? That should likely be used to set the input's value. Using it outside the loop will result in "last result" behavior.

Comment: $models is actually irrelevant here. I just forgot to take it out! Basically when I run this code, I would receive an input field for every result. But only the last result would post.

Comment: Maybe there is only *one* results? Check `mysql_num_rows`.